# This value is not a function and cannot be applied

Tags: f#

Pretty simple function for operation of negation.

```
let negation (value:option<bool>) =
   match value with
   |Some true -> Some false
   |Some false -> Some true
   |None -> failwith "OOPS"
```

but when i call it:

```
negation Some true
```

it complains that

```
This value is not a function and cannot be applied
```

Comment: Just a side note: If you don't really need to throw exception when parameter is `None` you could use this function: `let negation = Option.map not`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need some parens there:

```
negation (Some true)
```

Or:

```
negation <| Some true
```

Without the parens like that F# compiler would understand that line as

```
(negation Some) true
```

because function application is left-binding and then types are not match: negation would need to be of type: `('a -> option 'a) -> bool -> bool` which clearly isn't (is of type `bool option -> bool option`)

**In addition:** (opinion included)

Negation function is called `not : bool -> bool`. You are trying to use that on the bool wrapped by option, so maybe that should be sufficient:

```
let negation : bool option -> bool option = Option.map not
```

Comment: Why parens are needed?

Comment: I extended an answered to explain why they are needed.